# RISCV testing emulator

Tags: riscv

When I'm trying to run riscv emulator asm tests I faced with below error:

```
./emulator-DefaultCPPConfig +dramsim +max-cycles=100000000 +verbose +loadmem=output/rv64ui-p-amoand_d.hex none 2> output/rv64ui-p-amoand_d.out && [ $PIPESTATUS -eq 0 ]
/bin/sh: 1: [: -eq: unexpected operator
make: *** [output/rv64ui-p-amoand_d.out] Error 2
```

I followed your instruction in your [git](https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket-chip#what). It can build emulator without any error, but problem happens when it's trying to run tests.

I added `bash` behind of the command in the makefile and the first error solved but when I did that I got a new error:

```
bash ./emulator-DefaultCPPConfig +dramsim +max-cycles=100000000 +verbose +loadmem=output/rv64ui-p-amoswap_d.hex none 2> output/rv64ui-p-amoswap_d.out && [ $PIPESTATUS -eq 0 ]
make: *** [output/rv64ui-p-amoswap_d.out] Error 126
```

Comment: What's in the output/rv64ui-p-amoswap_d.out file?

Comment: I ran the test `make run-asm-tests` on another system, since I don't have access to that system but still I got the error but this time for: `output/rv64ui-p-add.out` . in this file there's just configuration of registers.

Comment: What is `[ $PIPESTATUS -eq 0 ]` command?

Comment: PIPESTATUS is a bash-ism that checks if the first command succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is from Shell variable, I just needed to add following line to Makefile:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

It would solve the problem.

Comment: Correct, the Makefile does not properly set the shell to use bash. You can try and workaround this by setting the SHELL environment variable to point to bash.